# Bash prefix command name for subcommands

Tags: git, bash

Is there a built-in way to implicitly specify a prefixed command name for any given subcommand in Bash?

For instance `git` has various subcommands, such as `status`, `branch`, `log`, `merge`, `commit`, etc., so what I would like to be able to do is something like;

```
export BASH_???=git # assume there is a variable or something to change Bash’s built-in behavior temporarily
status # instead of `git status`
branch # instead of `git branch`
...
```

P.S.: I am aware of https://github.com/thoughtbot/gitsh, https://github.com/rtomayko/git-sh, https://github.com/caglar/gitsh and https://github.com/defunkt/repl; but those projects “wrap” either `git` command or any command without honoring user’s settings (such as `PS1` or `PROMPT_COMMAND`, etc.)

Comment: Whether or not that's possible, you should think twice before following such an approach. By exposing all the Git subcommands like that, you would lose "namespacing" (for lack of a better term). What if you already have a shell command called `status`? Instead, why not define short aliases, such as `br` for `branch`, `st` for `status`, etc.?

Comment: @Jubobs thanks for your consideration. I am hoping to apply this approach “per-session” rather than applying for every shell instance.

Comment: The term "subcommand" does not mean that commands are somehow nested. It just refers to the single command `git` that runs another command in response to an ordinary string argument.

Comment: @chepner thanks for your comment, but could you please explain what do you mean by that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest I think you could do to having this would be to use command_not_found_handle (bash 4+) to do this indirection in your git "sessions".

Something like this roughly (untested):

```
command_not_found_handle() {
    if ! PAGER=cat git "$1" --help >/dev/null 2>&1; then
        return $?
    fi

    git "$@"
}
```

Comment: Oh, I like this one.  That trick with the `--help` is flat-out clever.  bash can redirect both stdout and stderr  with `&>` and git handles closed standard streams fine, so `git "$1" --help &>-` works too.

Comment: I assume it works, but I also think there is too much "black magic” involved here. Correct me if I am wrong, but when this applied, for any valid git subcommand that is also a command by it self, then you wouldn’t be able to run the command no more? For example, `diff` would run `git diff`, but then you wouldn’t be able to use plain `diff`. I think this would go better with something that “defines” and “undefines” `command_not_found_handle` when needed rather than “enabling” it “globally”.

Comment: Oh, and for the records: Mac OS Yosemite (`10.10.3`) comes bundled with `GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin14)`.

Comment: @etan-reisner do you know a similar approach for Bash <4 please?

Comment: exalted: command_not_found_handle won't be invoked for a command which exists, so `diff` would work fine. But as you say, it won't work for bash 3; the only simple solution for bash 3 is a massive list of aliases (which you might be able to generate automatically).

Comment: @jthill True I could have used `&>` here I just habitually avoid it and don't generally think about closing fd`s but if that works here that's good. I originally tried `PAGER=` but that caused git to throw an error so I had to go with `cat`.

Comment: For "recent" (I don't know what versions) you could use the (unfortunately ugly) output of `git help -a` to get a list of the available git commands and the output from `git config --get-regexp '^alias\.'` (or similar) to get any configured git aliases and create shell aliases for them all (as rici indicated) but that *would* override any commands of the same name (which this solution does not) so you would need to account for that somehow. This is likely why the wrapping shell solutions exist.

Comment: You might be able to do something evil in `PROMPT_COMMAND` with the return status of the last command and trying it *again* as a git command (a manual `command_not_found_handle` basically) but I don't know how well that would work.

Answer (score 1):

Given the namespace issues discussed in the comments, I would make explicit aliases for selected git sub-commands. For that you can use these bash functions

```
declare -a GITABBREVIATIONS=( status branch log merge commit )

function git_alias_init() {
   for cmd in "${GITABBREVIATIONS[@]}"; do
      alias "$cmd"='git '"$cmd"
   done
}

function git_alias_end() {
   for cmd in "${GITABBREVIATIONS[@]}"; do
      unalias "$cmd"
   done
}
```

which you have to paste into your `.bashrc` (or alternatively source with `source git-abbreviations.sh`). Then you can start your (alias) session with

```
$ git_alias_init
```

and end it with

```
$ git_alias_end
```

Comment: Interesting, and surprisingly simple approach I should say.

Comment: Although, totally ignores any configuration for the command (`git` in this example) itself. For example, if you have `alias.ci = commit` defined for git, then `alias commit=‘git commit’` would be present, not `alias ci=‘git ci’`. Tedious, but works.

Comment: @exalted If you need it, you can insert `ci` in the list of aliases, like `GITABBREVIATIONS=( status branch log merge commit ci )`

Comment: sure, you could do that.

Comment: @exalted Anyway, the solution by EtanReisner is much more elegant.

Comment: I am not sure if that’s true. It definitely is more “clever” though. Thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78021/discussion-between-exalted-and-user1978011).

Answer (score 0):

For the records, here is an alternative approach that could help whoever may be interested in the future.

The idea is to implement some sort of a `preexec` bash function that would run prior to every command that you could implement your own and accept/refuse commands or change, etc.

[Check it out.](http://www.twistedmatrix.com/users/glyph/preexec.bash.txt)